# I need help sort my images properly in CSS, HTML

Tags: html, css, image

I am new to web development and I am trying to make a website for sorting my pictures in CSS, HTML5. What I want the sorting to look like the text separates the images like a new paragraph.[how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3JGG.jpg) I tried to add

```
<br />
```

but that did not work as I expected. Thanks for any help I can get :)

```css
#pics {
  margin-top: 10px;
  max-width: 1500px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.pics-text {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 87%;
}

.pic-item {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-right: 7px;
}

.pic-item a img {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="pics">

  <h2 class="pics-text">some text</h2>

  <div class="pic-item">
    <a href="#"><img src="./imgs/123-vertical/1.jpg" /></a>
  </div>

  <div class="pic-item">
    <a href="#"><img src="./imgs/123-vertical/2.jpg" /></a>
  </div>

  <div class="pic-item">
    <a href="#"><img src="./imgs/123-vertical/3.jpg" /></a>
  </div>

</div>
<div id="pics">

  <h2 class="pics-text">some text</h2>

  <div class="pic-item">
    <a href="#"><img src="./imgs/123-vertical/1.jpg" /></a>
  </div>

  <div class="pic-item">
    <a href="#"><img src="./imgs/123-vertical/2.jpg" /></a>
  </div>

  <div class="pic-item">
    <a href="#"><img src="./imgs/123-vertical/3.jpg" /></a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: There is a very simple way of fixing this, adding 20+ lines that say ```<br />``` but I am looking for a more efficient way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-You need to put all your Items in a div and make your container div flex with column direction.
- IDs must be unic, so You are not allowed to use one id for multiple elements in your HTML Code.

```css
body{
  background-color:red;
}
.container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
#first, #second{
    margin-top: 10px;
    max-width: 1500px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.pics-text{
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  display:flex;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #ffffff;
    opacity: 87%;
}

.pic-item { 
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 20%;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-right: 7px;
}

.pic-item a img {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div id="first">

        <h2 class="pics-text">some text</h2>

        <div class="pic-item">
            <a href="#"><img src="https://images.redbullshop.com/is/image/RedBullSalzburg/RB-product-detail/RBS19168_3H_1/RBS-Champions-League-Ball.jpg" /></a>
        </div>

        <div class="pic-item">
            <a href="#"><img src="https://images.redbullshop.com/is/image/RedBullSalzburg/RB-product-detail/RBS19168_3H_1/RBS-Champions-League-Ball.jpg" /></a>
        </div>

        <div class="pic-item">
            <a href="#"><img src="https://images.redbullshop.com/is/image/RedBullSalzburg/RB-product-detail/RBS19168_3H_1/RBS-Champions-League-Ball.jpg" /></a>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="second">

        <h2 class="pics-text">some text</h2>

        <div class="pic-item">
            <a href="#"><img src="https://images.redbullshop.com/is/image/RedBullSalzburg/RB-product-detail/RBS19168_3H_1/RBS-Champions-League-Ball.jpg" /></a>
        </div>

        <div class="pic-item">
            <a href="#"><img src="https://images.redbullshop.com/is/image/RedBullSalzburg/RB-product-detail/RBS19168_3H_1/RBS-Champions-League-Ball.jpg" /></a>
        </div>

        <div class="pic-item">
            <a href="#"><img src="https://images.redbullshop.com/is/image/RedBullSalzburg/RB-product-detail/RBS19168_3H_1/RBS-Champions-League-Ball.jpg" /></a>
        </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Welcome, ask me if you needed, I'd be happy to help. :)

Answer (score 1):

So you want one image and a text below it or image and text beside?
If you want to some image and then some text then put all your Items in a div and make your container div flex with direction: column.

```
.first{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}
img{
  width: 50%
}
```

and the HTML would be

```
<h1>Some Text</h1>
<div class="first">
  <img src="https://img.favpng.com/20/20/8/football-sport-ball-game-png-favpng-8PPaPFsNEixHevLDVTnWJTegN.jpg" alt="football"/>
  <img src="https://img.favpng.com/20/20/8/football-sport-ball-game-png-favpng-8PPaPFsNEixHevLDVTnWJTegN.jpg" alt="football"/>
  <img src="https://img.favpng.com/20/20/8/football-sport-ball-game-png-favpng-8PPaPFsNEixHevLDVTnWJTegN.jpg" alt="football"/>
</div>
<h1>Some Text</h1>
<div class="first">
  <img src="https://img.favpng.com/20/20/8/football-sport-ball-game-png-favpng-8PPaPFsNEixHevLDVTnWJTegN.jpg" alt="football"/>
  <img src="https://img.favpng.com/20/20/8/football-sport-ball-game-png-favpng-8PPaPFsNEixHevLDVTnWJTegN.jpg" alt="football"/>
  <img src="https://img.favpng.com/20/20/8/football-sport-ball-game-png-favpng-8PPaPFsNEixHevLDVTnWJTegN.jpg" alt="football"/>
</div>
```